# Two domains in a single AWS ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, virtualhost, amazon-route53

I have two domains `domain1.com` & `domain2.com` & want to run both domains on a **single ec2 instance**.

I have created **2 hosted zones** for both domains and added **nameserver** in my domain provider.

domain1.com's code resides in - **/var/www/html**

domain2.com's code resides in - **/var/www/domain2**

Added virtual host for both respective domains in

> /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

virtual host looks like below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerAdmin webmaster@yourdomain.com
   DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
   ServerName domain1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

So when I run `domain1.com` that works perfectly fine, but when run `domain2.com` it show code from `/var/www/html` but it should show code from `/var/www/domain2`

So please help me to identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
# Ensure that Apache listens on port 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
    ServerName www.domain1.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/domain2"
    ServerName www.domain2.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

This will set up two `VirtualHosts` that respond to `domain1.com` and `domain2.com`, respectively. Note that the first `VirtualHost` for `domain1.com` will be seen as the primary host and will be the default responder for all requests that don't match any `ServerName`s.

[Other examples can be found here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: That does not work, you just added www in ServerName right?

Comment: How many instances of Apache are you running on your single EC2 instance?